# Run SELECT without use Buffer pool

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is possible with InnoDB to run SELECT without saving data to buffer pool? I have about 20% of SELECTs which read data only once and wasting about 40% of buffer pool. So it make sense to read this data always from disk. For query cache is great SQL_NO_CACHE, but I don't know about something for buffer pool.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly assign the tables that will and will not affect the InnoDB Buffer Pool. But, you can paralyse the rotation of Buffer Pool pages at MySQL startup with the following two options:

[innodb_old_blocks_pct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_pct)

> Specifies the approximate percentage of the InnoDB buffer pool used for the old block sublist. The range of values is 5 to 95. The default value is 37 (that is, 3/8 of the pool). See Section 14.16.2.3, “Making the Buffer Pool Scan Resistant” for more information. See Section 8.9.1, “The InnoDB Buffer Pool” for information about buffer pool management, such as the LRU algorithm and eviction policies.

[innodb_old_blocks_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_time)

> Specifies how long in milliseconds (ms) a block inserted into the old sublist must stay there after its first access before it can be moved to the new sublist. If the value is 0, a block inserted into the old sublist moves immediately to the new sublist the first time it is accessed, no matter how soon after insertion the access occurs. If the value is greater than 0, blocks remain in the old sublist until an access occurs at least that many ms after the first access. For example, a value of 1000 causes blocks to stay in the old sublist for 1 second after the first access before they become eligible to move to the new sublist.